# Shared Bugzilla with SSL and mod_perl has login cookie issues

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, bugzilla, mod-perl

I've managed to set up a shared mod_perl Bugzilla environment using the PROJECT variable, and it works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing on a different server, with the same basic setup, except that the hosts sharing Bugzilla are running SSL as well. That means they also have different, unique IP addresses.

Although this second setup basically works, I'm running into problems with login and cookies. Logins for the two Bugzillas interfere with each other, causing repeated login prompts and 'bad password' messages. Apparently this is fairly common with certain Bugzilla setups, but note that I do not have that problem with my original shared mod_perl Bugzilla (the one without SSL).

I believe Bugzilla defaults to sharing cookies, and that's presumably the root of the problem, and I've tried playing with both cookiepath and cookiedomain, with no success.

Has anyone out there cracked this problem?

Additional: I'm running Bugzilla 4.4.4. Bugzilla1 is bugs.domain1.com; its cookiedomain is '' and cookiepath is '/'. Bugzilla2 is bugs.domain2.com; its cookiedomain is '' and cookiepath is '/'.

Although normally when making changes to a Bugzilla/mod_perl setup I restart Apache to allow changes to kick in, my understanding is that this is not necessary when only the params files are changed (including changes to cookiedomain and cookiepath) (confirmed).

I tried setting the two cookiedomain values to 'bugs.domain1.com/' and 'bugs.domain2.com/', but that just resulted in no cookies being created at all.

I used LiveHTTPHeaders to watch what happens with the login-related Bugzilla cookies. As long as the two Bugzillas are working normally (no spurious login prompts), the cookies being passed around make sense. Before login, the Bugzilla_login_request_cookie is set with a unique value. After login, Bugzilla_login_request_cookie is effectively cleared, and two new cookies are set: Bugzilla_login and Bugzilla_logincookie. When one of the Bugzillas suddenly prompts for login again, although I see no change in the cookies being passed to the server in the GET header, the server returns this:

```
Set-Cookie: Bugzilla_login_request_cookie=<new value>; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

Something is making Bugzilla think the user is no longer logged in, and Bugzilla is responding by setting a new value for Bugzilla_login_request_cookie, which triggers the login process again.

Update: On the advice of a Bugzilla developer, I've reported this as a bug ([#1005931](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005931)) in the Bugzilla bug tracking system (Bugzilla).

Comment: If you turn off SSL on the new server, does it start working? If so, I suspect that you're accidentally creating some kind of cross-site "attack" that's being blocked.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the domain names you are using, and their structure. (E.g. "Bugzilla 1 is foo.example.com and Bugzilla 2 is bar.example.com. My cookiepath is X and my cookiedomain is Y.)

Comment: Also, what Bugzilla version are you using? The release notes for 4.4.2 say:

"The PROJECT environment variable is now correctly taken into account when mod_perl is enabled (this variable allows several installations to share the same codebase)."

Comment: @GervaseMarkham: good points. I've updated the question.

Comment: @bombcar: turning off SSL as a test is something I've considered, but it's problematic since one of the two Bugzillas is in production. Still, if nothing else pans out, I'll give it a try after hours.

Comment: Those blank cookiedomains look suspicious - can you try setting them to reflect the servername? My bugzilla cookies have a domain set (bugs.domain.com) - even though my cookiedomain is blank. Do your cookies correctly show the right domain?

Comment: Another option would be to configure (on a test server) a dual shared-SSL setup using SNI and a single IP.

Comment: The cookies show the correct domain. In Firefox, the cookies show as 'Host: bugs.domain1.com' and 'Host: bugs.domain2.com'. I noticed that some other cookies (unrelated to Bugzilla) show 'Domain' instead of 'Host'. Is that weird? Cookies are weird. I'll try setting cookiedomain for both sites to match the root URLs.

Comment: Regarding the test setup you mentioned: good idea. I have a Linux VM lying around somewhere.

Comment: Although an Apache restart should not be required, it would be one of the first things I'd try to see if it made any difference...

Comment: What values are you using for your PROJECT variables? Specifically, do they match the Perl regexp /^(\w+)$/ or not? Are you certain that the two Bugzillas are in fact using separate localconfig.$PROJECT files, and not both or either using the standard localconfig without an extension?

Comment: Have you tried using LiveHTTPHeaders or similar Firefox extension to watch the HTTP requests? Clear out all cookies for both domains. Then log into one, and check that the various headers are right. Then access the other and see if cookies are being sent. Then log in to that one. When you get a login error, check to see what cookies were sent.

It helps if your userid (Bugzilla_login cookie) is different between the two installations.

Comment: I changed the cookiedomain setting for both Bugzillas, to 'bugs.domain1.com/' and 'bugs.domain2.com/'. Restarted Apache to be sure. Now I get constant login prompts for both, and Firefox is showing no cookies for either Bugzilla. Did I get the syntax wrong? Should I include 'https://'? What about that training slash?

Comment: Bugzilla1 doesn't use the PROJECT variable, so it just uses the default localconfig. Bugzilla2 sets PROJECT to 'domain2'. I know it's working because I've set 'announcehtml' in the params file to a unique value. I also confirmed that changes to params appear immediately, without an Apache restart.

Answer (score 0):

From your additional reporting, this sounds like a bug in the new mechanism we added to prevent login-page XSRF. Please can you file it at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ ? Thanks :-)

There's only one place in the code this cookie is set - CGI.pm line 314 (on trunk). And it's only set if Bugzilla thinks there's no logged-in user. And, as you say, that should not be so.

Gerv

Comment: Interesting. But before I report this as a Bugzilla bug in the Mozilla Bugzilla Bugzilla, I'd like to make sure it's really a bug. Can you provide any additional insight into how I can test whether the new anti-XSRF mechanism is actually failing?